# VBA CommandBarButton does not run code OnAction

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

Once the button is pressed it does not perform the subroutine defined **OnAction** method.

I have checked all the Security options in Access are enabled and have written the same code in different ways.

I have tried to run a function with the **OnAction** method instead.

```vb
Private Sub Check_Status_Click()
    Dim cmdBAR As CommandBar
    Dim cmdButton1 As CommandBarButton

    Set cmdBAR = CommandBars.Add(, msoBarPopup, False, True)
    Set cmdButton1 = cmdBAR.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)

    cmdButton1.Caption = "Dale"
    cmdButton1.OnAction = "Dale"
    cmdBAR.ShowPopup

    'Clean
    Set cmdBAR = Nothing
    Set cmdButton1 = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Dale()
    MsgBox "hola"
End Sub
```

I dont get any error, just it is not doing anything even the menu shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Actually **OnAction** subroutine needs to be

1. public sub
2. in public module

So you should change your code to something like this:

```vb
...
    cmdButton1.Caption = "Dale"
    cmdButton1.OnAction = "Dale"
    cmdBAR.ShowPopup
...
```

And place your sub into some public module:

```vb
Public Sub Dale()
    MsgBox "hola"
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove requirement 2. It doesn't need to be a function.  If its called as a sub it would be `.OnAction = "yourSub"`, if its a function it should be called as `.OnAction = "=yourFunction()"`

Comment: If you use the =MyFuction() format, then the function can be in the current forms code module that has the focus. This allows you to call the same function in different forms with a common menu/command bar. So, say =MyDelete() can call this function in the given form, and each form that has the current focus will thus get its own custom routine called - which is a exactly what you want - this trick also applies to ribbons. Using a =MyFuncNmae() means that a ribbon can run code inside of each form that has the focus. So, scratch the 2nd requirement too! Only requirement marking function public.

Comment: I have a workbook in Excel and found a problem on a client pc.  `.OnAction = "yourSub"` does not work. However `.OnAction = "=yourSub()"` works. This only occures on one PC though? Is it saver to always use `"=yourSub()"` ?

Comment: @DrMarbuse while a procedure sometimes works, a function always works. But you have to be careful with the types of data this function returns, for example arrays will cause an error if you use the function in a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Although, the question is related to Access, I post my soultion related to Excel, as it seems the problem is identical.

It seems, Excel VBA interprets the '.OnAction'-String differently in different Versions. However, I found, that a function is not called twice and worked on all versions of Excel and VBA, that I tested:

`.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "'MyFunctionA ("""")'"`

Also, the blank before the `(` was important. And `MyFunctionA` is a public function with an (in my case optional) argument.

Comment: There is an unknown compatibility issue.
In some of the current Office installations, the OnAction command only works without the workbook part:
`.OnAction =  "'MyFunctionA ("""")'"`
Very confusing. Not good.