# VBA Excel CommandBarButton OnAction property causes error and has to be defined differently

Tags: excel, vba

There is a strange behaviour in Excel. After Windows-Update on a PC (Windows Version 10.0.19045 and Office 365 Apps for Bussiness 16.0.16026.20196, 32-bit) the `OnAction` property of CommandBarButtons have to be defined unsing `.OnAction = "=myProcedure()"` instead of `.OnAction = "myProcedure"`.

`myProcedure` is a `Public Sub` in one of the VBA-Modules.

The following code does work on most Systems, but does NOT work on the particular System:

```
'
' see:
' https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/office.commandbarbutton.onaction
'
'
Set myBar = CommandBars("Custom") 
Set myControl = myBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msocontrolButton) 
With myControl 
    .FaceId = 2 
    .OnAction = "MySub" 
End With
```

To work correctly, I had to change the code to:
The following code does work on most Systems, but does NOT work on the particular System:

```
Set myBar = CommandBars("Custom") 
Set myControl = myBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msocontrolButton) 
With myControl 
    .FaceId = 2 
    .OnAction = "=MySub()" 
End With
```

The procedure for adding the control is VBA-Code, that is called from a .NET Office-Ribbon-Addin. Maybe this causes the strange behaviour? Do you have any clue?

Comment: I found a hint for a similar problem in MS Access: [VBA CommandBarButton does not run code OnAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171443/vba-commandbarbutton-does-not-run-code-onaction)

Comment: After some more testing, Excel seems to run the procedure **twice** if defined with `.OnAction = "=MySub()"`. It seems to be a buggy behaviour of Excel.

Comment: Strange... I tested (Excel Mondo 2016 - Windows 11) and it runs the procedure twice. More than that, I placed a break point on the first code line of called sub and **it never stops on it**. Then, I suppose that it somehow embeds the called procedure and changed its name. It returned an error. After correcting the name, it raised an error saying that cannot find it...